# Detect microphone is attached or not using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a site in **ASP.NET MVC 4** framework and using **recorder.js** to record the sound. It is working fine on chrome.

I need to identify if **microphone is attached to system** or not using **jQuery**. If microphone is not attached I need to show alert to attach microphone.

Comment: jquery cannot access system hardware..it resides on the client browser.

Comment: Maybe this link (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) can help you.